# WebSocket In SYNC_SENT State

Tags: tcp, firewall

I have a problem in establishing a connection with using websocket.

[image]

FYI, the target that we wish to connect to is 10.121.244.17:45678 which is an instance of socket server. The problematic executable is covered in Red which let say represents `ABC.exe`.

As you can see in the console, both requests to connect with the socket server have been redirected to `116.206.196.77:3128` which I am not really convinced that it is a firewall.

This is because I have used `puttyTel.exe` to test the connection of the socket server and it did work which can be seen at the console output.

Besides, pinging to address of `116.206.196.77` returns `request timed out`.

Thus, is there any way i can know when is the SYNC request being redirected to this address?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network, or on [su] for a personal network.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, i will redirect the post to the related site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`...:3128` looks like a HTTP proxy port. Since Windows doesn't provide (much) proxy connectivity, this is probably set up in puTTY. Alternatively, look at Windows's Internet settings.

`SYN_SENT` means that a TCP connection is trying to get up but there's no `ACK` coming back. Either the destination is not responding or the routing doesn't work.

For a more detailed answer you need to add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi, can you explain more on proxy connectivity that was set up in puTTY? Do you mean that the normal connection request by ABC.exe is going through a proxy thus changing its address?

Comment: Hi, any kind of extra details still needed for troubleshooting purpose as i am really clueless on networking stuff?

Comment: Hi, as for the routing, I think it works because i can get the computer name with `ping -a 10.121.244.17`.

Comment: Hi, the problem is due to proxy server. Thanks alot for your help.